# How to apply FadeIn and FadeOut effect to DIV inside UpdatePanel using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, fadein

I have a two `DIV's` in my page for demonstration for now. `Div1` show the entry form and `Div2` allows the user to Edit the entered form fields. Both the `Div's` are in `UpdatePanel`.

**Here is the scenario:**

--User enter the Details in `Div1` and clicks on `"Continue"` which is `LinkButton`. on click the `Div1` `Visible` property is set to `False` and `Div2` `Visible` is set to `True`.

--When `Div2` is `Visible` and user `Click` on `Edit LinkButton` then `Div1` is `Visible` and  `Div2` `Visible` property is set to `False`.

Here is Markup:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="Server">

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(beginRequestDBR);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(endRequestDBR);
        function InitEvent() {
            $(document).on("click", "#ctl00_MainContent_lnkEditShipping", function() {
                alert("hi");
                //fadeIn(speed[milliseconds], easing[linear], callback)
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_divShippingPanel").fadeIn(1500);
                $("#ctl00_MainContent_divShippingConfirmPanel").fadeOut(2000);
                // $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_divShippingPanel").fadeOut(2000);
                //return false;

            });


        }
        function beginRequestDBR(sender, args) {
            //some code here 
        }

        function endRequestDBR(sender, args) {

            //some code here 
        }

        $(document).ready(InitEvent);
    </script>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div id="divShippingPanel" runat="server">
                <div style="margin-top: 10px;">
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <label>
                                    First Name</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <label>
                                    Last Name</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSAFirstName" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSAFirstName"
                                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter First Name" Font-Bold="false" Font-Italic="false">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSALastName" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtSALastName"
                                    Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter Last Name" Font-Bold="false" Font-Italic="false">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <label>
                                    Address Line 1</label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <label>
                                    Address Line 2(optional)</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSAAdd1" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                &nbsp;
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSAAdd2" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <label>
                                    City</label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <label>
                                    State</label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <label>
                                    Zip Code</label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSACity" runat="server" Width="150px"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="drpSAState" class="drpSAState" runat="server" Width="175">
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="">--</asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Value="AL">Alabama</asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSAZIP" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="left">
                                <label>
                                    Phone (optional)</label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <label>
                                    Country</label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="padding-left: 5px;">
                                <label>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSAPhone" runat="server" Width="150"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <b>United States</b> We currently only support trades within the United States.
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <label>
                                </label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <br />
                <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: left;">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkShippingPanel" runat="server" CssClass="button orange" OnClick="lnkContinue_Click"
                        OnClientClick="return ValidateInput();">Continue</asp:LinkButton>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="divShippingConfirmPanel" visible="false" runat="server">
                <h2 style="color: black; margin: 0 0 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: medium;
                    margin-top: 20px;">
                    Please confirm your address</h2>
                <p>
                    <h2 style="color: #888; margin: 0 0 10px;">
                        We verify all addresses to assure fast and accurate delivery.</h2>
                    <p>
                    </p>
                    <div style="font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #a73316; padding: 10px 0;">
                        <p>
                            This address is not recognized by the USPS. Are you sure you want to use it?</p>
                        <p>
                            Do the city, state, or ZIP code conflict?
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            Are there other major typos?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <h2>
                            Your input</h2>
                        <p>
                            <asp:Label ID="lblYourInput" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div id="divVerfiedAddress">
                        <b>0 verified addresses</b>
                    </div>
                    <div style="padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkConfirmShipping" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="button orange"
                            OnClick="lnkContinue_Click" OnClientClick="return ValidateInput();">Confirm</asp:LinkButton>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkEditShipping" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" CommandArgument="3"
                            CssClass="button orange" OnClick="lnkEditInfo_Click">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void lnkContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Get the data entered in textboxes assign to Business objects and then show next div
        divShippingPanel.Visible = false;
        divShippingConfirmPanel.Visible = true;   
}
protected void lnkEditInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string currentStep = (sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument;

    if (currentStep == "3")
    {
        //if arument is 3 go back i.e currentstep-1 for editing the details
       divShippingPanel.Visible = true;
       divShippingConfirmPanel.Visible = false;
    }
}
```

**This works But i want to apply fadein,fadeout effect using jquery.**

**Any Suggestions!**

**NOTE: Both Div's are server side div with attribute runat="server".**

Comment: this can be easily achived the display/hide part of the div's is handled on the client side rather that server side

Comment: but how to maintain the state after postback..?

Comment: Instead of using a `runat=server`, you could rather use an asp.net hidden field to store the state and use jquery to show/hide the div on page load using the hidden field values